# Are there any alternatives to the Associated Press' Elections API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I am writing an application that requires live election results for the upcoming 2016 general election.  We need presidential, Senate, House, and gubernatorial results on both a nationwide and state-by-state level.  As far as I've been able to discover, only the [U.S. Associated Press' Elections API](https://developer.ap.org/ap-elections-api) seems to provide this information.

There are other elections data APIs, such as [Google's Civic Information](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/), but they only provide historical and demographic information, not live polling results. A company called PollyVote provides election forecasts, but no live poll returns.

The AP has a very large subscription fee for their Elections API, are they really the only source for this type of data?